# Can't get my <Insert> key to remap

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm new to VIM and using the Janus plugin collection on MacVim.

For whatever reason the  key is mapped to :help.  And I can't figure out how the heck to get it remapped.  I want it to remap so that it goes into Insert from normal mode, and then goes back to normal mode from insert mode.  I found this snippet somewhere else and have loaded it into my .vimrc, but no love... it still maps to help.

```
nnoremap <Insert> i
inoremap <Insert> <Esc>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or, how can I find out WHERE  is mapped to :help?

thx

Comment: If this is terminal vim (not macvim), chances are that your terminal sends unexpected control codes for special keys (which vim then might interpret as containing `<F1>` (for help)... That's a long shot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>`<Insert>`</kbd> is the 'oldfashioned' insert key

The one on the numeric keypad is <kbd>`<kInsert>`</kbd>

You can have a look what is currently mapped by doing

```
:map <Insert>    
:map <kInsert>
```

Comment: Hmm, that's good to know.  This Insert is actually not the one on the "0" on the numpad, but one of six keys above arrow keys on a full sized keyboard.  What's really strange is that if I type :map and then that key, its coming out as <Help>!

Comment: Ok, so I just replaced <Insert> with <Help> and it works...  Thanks for the lead anyway.  Now I know to type :map and then the key to figure out what it thinks the key is.  Much appreciated!

Comment: What comes out when you type it in letters, like I showed? `:map <Insert>` - if it still says `<Help>` then it is simply being mapped from a plugin or your vimrc(s). If not, then you've succesfully diagnosed wrong terminal keycodes :)